# PCL RANSAC 3D ellipse model fitting

Tags: c++, geometry, point-cloud-library, point-clouds, pcl

The pcl_sample_consensus library holds SAmple Consensus (SAC) methods like RANSAC and models like planes and cylinders. I want to model 3D ellipse. I want to have model coefficients of 3D ellipse. Do you know any function to do it?

Answer (score 2):

You can write your own class that inherits from class [SampleConsensusModel](https://pointclouds.org/documentation/classpcl_1_1_sample_consensus_model.html#details), and then use that as a model.

An ellipse in 3d should be relatively similar to a circle in 3d, so you could copy the code of [SampleConsensusModelCircle3d](https://pointclouds.org/documentation/classpcl_1_1_sample_consensus_model_circle3_d.html#ad877b27b33f5c22f67b354fd9066c9d2) and modify it to have an Ellipse3d class instead of a Circle3d class.

Or if by "3d ellipse" you meant an [ellipsoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsoid), then you could copy the code from [SampleConsensusModelSphere](https://pointclouds.org/documentation/classpcl_1_1_sample_consensus_model_sphere.html#abc072484d6bd528c0b99160ef780cd84) and modify it go have an Ellipsoid class.

You'd think someone would have done that already, but I wasn't able to find an Ellipse implementation of SampleConsensusModel with a google search. If you do end up implementing your own, or if you find that someone else implemented one already, please write an answer here!